# Openshift template generation

Tags: templates, openshift

I have a question about Openshift.

I know it is possible to backup all the artifact for a project to a yaml or json file and use that as a backup to then restore the project/create the project somewhere else. But is it possible to create a template from an existing project? For example, I've this project that runs a specific build and has specific settings. I want to generate a template, modify some of the settings to have it point to another set of url and then have it run. For all intent and purposes, everything will be the same for both projects except for a couple settings.

I'm thinking I can go through and copy the yaml for each deployment,build and PVC, but it seems quite hack-y so I'm curious if there's an actual built-in way of doing this.

TL;DR: Can I copy an openshift project/create a clone of it?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no automatic way for it except use of Podman generate (if you looking for something like that.)

see https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/01/29/podman-kubernetes-yaml/

and also https://blog.openshift.com/part-2-creating-a-template-a-technical-walkthrough/

Comment: Yes, after a few days of working on it, it does seem that there is no real way of doing this. What I found out worked for us was exporting the yaml for all our routes, builds and secrets and then manually editing them before importing. It's inefficient, but is our current best solution